# Sending discord direct message by user ID using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

i made a discord bot that sends messages by user id. 
the problem is that i cannot run this bot.
the code is:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(' [!] messaging..\n')
 
    with open("ids.json", "r") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
 
    indx = 0
    for i in data:
        indx += 1
        member = await bot.fetch_user(i)
        try:
            await member.send("message to send")
            print(f" [+] Sent message {indx} / {len(data)}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f" [!] {e}")
 
    print(" [+] Done")
 
bot.run("bot token", bot = False)
```

**And the error I get is:**

```py
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 17, in on_ready
    member = await bot.fetch_user(i)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 1384, in fetch_user
    data = await self.http.get_user(user_id)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 250, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10013): Unknown User
```

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 means not found.

So in discord error 404 means user not found.

So check your user id and try again

Answer (score 0):

## IDs need to be ints

```py
with open("ids.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
 
indx = 0
for i in data:
    indx += 1
    member = await bot.fetch_user(i)
    # and so on...
```

The problem here is that JSON keys (assuming the data is a object, if it's a array then just make the items int by removing the quotes) cannot be anything other than strings, but fetch_user expects an int. another thing is that fetch_user does an API call in order to get the user, you should use get_user instead to avoid spamming the API. another thing is that you should use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of making a variable then increasing that variable on each iteration

#### So the reformatted code is

```py
with open("ids.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
 

for indx, i in enumerate(data, start=1):
    indx += 1
    member = bot.get_user(int((i))
    # and so on...
```